# add brush capability in d3 line chart

Tags: d3.js

I am editing with the latest code which is available in the fiddle

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nj11eruq/10/

I have reached the last leg. Now i could brush the graph and the graph gets redrawn for the selected area. I can zoom in to a detail level. However i need to reset the graph when i double click/ click the graph (no resizing brush). I am missing something here.

Comment: are you able to put a JSFiddle together so we can edit your code ?

Comment: sure. I have added the code in http://fiddle.jshell.net/nj11eruq/1/

Comment: I am not sure how to retrieve the values from csv in jsfiddle. so i created a html element tag filled with the data and tried to read it. however the graph is not working in fiddle. it works fine if we read through the asynch d3.csv call. I will edit the code so that just copying it in html and creating a csv in same folder should work fine.

Comment: I directly added the data in the code instead of pre element data. http://fiddle.jshell.net/nj11eruq/2/ but not sure why the data is not getting displayed but no error displayed in result.

Comment: you havent added D3 as an external resource, however it still doesn't work when that gets applied :/

Comment: i have selected d3 3.0 version in the framework and extensions onload. I thought it would be ok. is there any way to find the error why it is not getting displayed?

Comment: F12 then go to console, you have an error 'undefined is not a function' ....

Comment: thanks AJ_91. I was able to debug and find the solution. the latest working code is in http://fiddle.jshell.net/nj11eruq/8/. I want to brush the graph and the graph should be redrawn to the brushed portion. it is a zoom kind of functionality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74813/discussion-between-user2010243-and-aj-91).

Answer (score 0):

finally, found out the way to implement the same. (of course some more optimizations,validations expected)
http://fiddle.jshell.net/nj11eruq/12